# How to do CSS reset in javafx and is it a good practice?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

When you have to completely customize a UI to your liking, and you're not 100% familiar with current underlying skin, it's a nightmare trying to hunt down which css class does what and related pseudo classes.

For ex., i spent hours trying to customize a `TableRow` appearance when selected; giving up at the end and just having it overridden with `setRowFactory`.

What is the **good practice** when having to do complete UI overhauls?

Comment: The [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) can help with styling. It gives you properties, substructures, and pseudo classes of various components.

Comment: @Slaw , yes i use that. But that describes the spec, not the implementation. For example, the one thing i needed was to change row appearance. The guide doesn't mention rows. I had to extract the `modena.css` from the java modules file to find `table-row-cell` css class. Which is the main issue.

Comment: nothing good or bad - you just have to do it :) In addition, to the reference guide (which is incomplete, not sure, if that's intentional or not) study modena as an example and roll your own (you can re-use the refs defined in there and use your own values)